# Text encoding error while using http get/post request within android application and a php server?

Tags: php, android, http, encoding, get

I'm developing an android app that sends an http get/post request to a server and receive the response as a string. The server uses php to retrieve get/post request.

> http://amazinginside.esy.es/devolopment.php?name=Sangeeth

This is my request. And my OnCreate() implementation is

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ServerConnect s=new ServerConnect();
        try
        {
            String[] params={"name","Sangeeth"};
            String request=s.Get("http://amazinginside.esy.es/devolopment.php",params);
            TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);
            textView.setText(request);
        }
        catch(ExecutionException e)
        {
            //Exception handling
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            //Exception handling
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the Server connect class

```
    public class ServerConnect
{

    public static String Get(String s ,String[] a) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        String parameters = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            try {
                parameters += a[i] + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(a[i + 1], "UTF-8") + "&";
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }
        return new DownloadWebpageTask().execute(s+"?"+parameters,"GET","").get();
    }

    public static String Post(String s ,String[] a) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        String parameters ="";

        for(int i=0; i<a.length ;i++){
            try {
                parameters += a[i]+"=" + URLEncoder.encode(a[i+1],"UTF-8")+"&";
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }


        return new DownloadWebpageTask().execute(s,"POST",parameters).get();

    }

    private static class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

// params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
            try {
                return downloadUrl(urls[0] ,urls[1],urls[2] );
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
            }
        }

        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        }

        private String downloadUrl(String myurl ,String method , String data) throws IOException {
            InputStream is = null;
// Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
// web page content.


            try {
                URL url = new URL(myurl);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod(method);
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                if (method == "POST") {
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);

                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                    out.print(data);
                    out.close();
                }
                // Starts the query
                conn.connect();
                int response = conn.getResponseCode();
                is = conn.getInputStream();

                // Convert the InputStream into a string


                String contentAsString = readIt(is, conn.getContentLength());
                return contentAsString;


                // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
                // finished using it.
            } finally {
                if (is != null) {
                    is.close();
                }
            }
        }

        private String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
            int n = 0;
            char[] buffer = new char[1024 * 4];
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF8");
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            while (-1 != (n = reader.read(buffer))) writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
            return writer.toString();
        }


    }
```

Here comes my PHP server script

```
    <?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    if($_GET["name"])
    {
        echo "Server responded : ".$_GET["name"];
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Server revoked";
    }
    ?>
```

When using Google Chrome or IE or Edge, I'm getting the result perfectly. But when I use my app to request the server, I'm getting the response back but it is unreadable. May be there is an encoding mismatch. But when I'm using a localhost (I'm using WampServer), I got the readable response in app too.
See : [IMAGE OF WHAT IM GETTING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Han5z.png)
Is there is a problem with my code or the server script? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set the request to the textview instead of the response.

```
 try
        {
            String[] params={"name","Sangeeth"};
            String request=s.Get("http://amazinginside.esy.es/devolopment.php",params);
            TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);
   =======> textView.setText(request);
        }
```

Once you send Async request to the server, set the textview to the response received in postExecute function of async task.

```
        //onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          (yourInstanceOfTextView).setText(result);
        }
```

And a better way to build the URI is to use [URI](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) class and [URI.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html) class

Comment: No way, I've implemented my textview instance inside onPostExecute() but still getting a wild encoded string

Comment: I found my answer now. It was caused by that excess 2 lines in my download url function.